# How to make a small storage in my macbook to act as a USB stick?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, scanning

I want to partition 128Mb out of my macbook hard drive and use it as an external usb; mainly for scanners that they can stick a usb stick into. This way I won't need to install drivers for every scanner I use.

Is that possible? Is there a small app that can make it? Convert the usb port into a usb stick on option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean use the partition as a USB drive on an external scanner?  If you start the computer in target disk mode and plug it into the scanner with a USB cord, this may work.

If you're running Mountain Lion or Mavericks, you can use Disk Utility to add a small, FAT  formatted partition to your hard drive without erasing it or losing any data.

Connecting that partition to an external scanner may prove to be trickier than installing drivers for a scanner.

Comment: I dont want to restart my computer to write something into a usb. so the main thing i need is to make a port be a usb stick. like if i even connect one port of my mac to another port in another laptop it will see as a removable in that laptop. I am going to see what I can do, maybe write a program or something. :)

Comment: @Gasim: If you write a program, post the info here!